# Decode Text from Request.InputStream in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, encoding, decoding

I'm trying to retrieve data from a hidden input of my HTML:

```
<INPUT type="hidden" name="HIDDENQUESMINV" id="HIDDENQUESMINV" value="@@Mínimo">
```

When I try to get its value by Request.InputStrem after submit the form I get this text: @@M%C3%ADnimo

My HTML is UTF-8 and it's good when I see it throught F12, but the request change the format. I tried to decode it, to change the encoding of the request but nothing works at all. I'm kinda lost of this and I wouldnt like to replace all this characters.

Thanks you,
Miguel.

Comment: In web.config, under `<system.web>...</system.web>` add `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />`. All request and response will be of **UTF-8** type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value is [Percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), as this is needed for transfer via HTTP protocol. You 
can decode it using

```
string decoded_value = Uri.UnescapeDataString(value_from_input_stream);
```

But I wonder why do you read value from InputStream? It is much easier to read value simply as

```
string decoded_value = Request.Form["HIDDENQUESMINV"];
```

if form is sent using POST method, or

```
string decoded_value = Request.QueryString["HIDDENQUESMINV"];
```

when form is sent using GET method. This way, values are already decoded, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks you, It worked! As a MIT Student and superinteligent person you can be really proud of receiving my agreement.